# Why is the output of "git reflog" different whether it is piped or not?

Tags: git

I'm curious about a difference of behavior with the "git reflog" command whether it is piped or not.

In a sample git repo, the output of "git reflog -2" is (with colors):

```
$ git reflog -2
1774192 (HEAD -> main, origin/main, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{0}: pull: Fast-forward
6cd001c HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from dev to main
```

Whereas the output of "git reflog -2 | cat" is (with no colors):

```
$ git reflog -2 | cat
1774192 HEAD@{0}: pull: Fast-forward
6cd001c HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from dev to main
```

I understand why git removes the color special chars when it is piped. But I don't get why it would remove the branch infos on the first line. It may be interesting to grep this info in script.

Anyone has an idea why it is useful ?

Edit: git version 2.42.0

Comment: Add `--decorate`.

Comment: Thanks. Adding "--decorate --color" to the piped command does restore the same behavior as the version without the pipe. :-)

Comment: Perhaps see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41280494/how-to-configure-git-output-when-piped though it discusses a different subcommand.